# Get today's date at midnight or no minutes and seconds

Tags: .net, asp.net, datetime

How can I get the current date but at midnight in a date object instead of a string object?

I know I can do this `Date.Now.ToShortDateString`, but that returns a string object. 
But if I do this `Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Now.ToShortDateString)`, it seems like too much code. Let me know if I should just get over this and use it.

Reason, I need to compare two dates and the date I'm comparing it to only has a date and no time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `DateTime.Today` field specifically for that purpose.
You can also use `DateTime.Date` property to get just the date of any datetime object, so `DateTime.Now.Date` will also work.

Comment: @guanome, no problem, sometimes the problem just needs another set of eyes.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the `Date` property:

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property on `DateTime` to get the `Date` with the time set to midnight for a given instance of `DateTime`.

```
// dateTime is an instance of DateTime
var date = dateTime.Date;
```

And more specifically, you can say

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
```

to get the current date at midnight (this is the same as saying)

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
```